# While using Protractor, when clicking a button which causes an http request to be made, I receive this: error while waiting for protractor to sync

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

```
describe("I should see a a list of cars to add ", function() {
  var add_car_button = element(by.id('add_car'));
  add_car_btn.click() // Failure, can't continue on from here
  // assertions to follow...
});
```

The error received from Protractor when running the test:

> error while waiting for protractor to sync

The `add_car_btn` will send the user to a new page where a list of cars (gathered via an http get request) will be displayed to the user. How can I successfully instruct the webdriver to click the button without failing to continue onward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the failing code within a beforeEach block is a successful workaround, see https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/376